# what type of slider is perfect for responsive website?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I have seen many well known sites like https://www.airbnb.com/ which are using responsive slider. This slider is very light and perfectly responsive. I have used Camera slider and layer slider (both static and wp version). These slider either take too much time for loading at start or they don't get responsive perfectly. I am looking for a very light and perfectly responsive slider for my website. please have a look to airbnb's slider and suggest me any nice thing like this one, which can play videos and can slide banners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BxSlider seems to be a good responsive slider, you can customize it and add  html code as you want.

It's ok with video.

You can read the doc to see if it's best way for your usage: [bxslider doc](http://bxslider.com).